# Flatten many to many relation for a csv export

Tags: mysql

I've to flatten a many to many relationship in order to make a csv export.

My tables :

> User:

```
------------
|id | Name |
------------
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Doe  |
```

> User_Group:

```
-------------------
|idUser | idGroup |
-------------------
| 1     | 1       |
| 1     | 2       |
| 2     | 2       |
```

> Group :

```
------------
|id | Name |
------------
| 1 | Foo  |
| 2 | Bar  |
```

And I want an output like so :

```
--------------------------------
| Name | Foo group | Bar group |
--------------------------------
| John | x         | x         |
| Doe  |           | x         |
```

I'm totally lost and have no idea of what I should do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, he needs joins combined with a pivot query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic pivot query combined with a few joins will give you the result you want:

```
SELECT t.name,
    CASE WHEN SUM(t.FooGroup) > 0 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS `Foo group`,
    CASE WHEN SUM(t.BarGroup) > 0 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS `Bar group`
FROM
(
    SELECT u.Name,
        CASE WHEN g.Name = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FooGroup,
        CASE WHEN g.Name = 'Bar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BarGroup
    FROM User u INNER JOIN User_Group ug
        ON u.id = ug.idUser
    INNER JOIN Group g
        ON ug.idGroup = gl.id
) t
GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't seems to work, the syntax is not correct

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
(
    SELECT u.Name,
        CASE WHEN g.Name = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ' at line 4`  --- I'm using `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.12-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Comment: Remove the comma after the second outer `CASE` statement.  Copy my query again and try it once more, it should work.

Comment: Awesome ! Works like a charm, thanks a lot ! Never heard about pivot queries, I'll do some searches about it.